# Как отправить деньги на карту через Qiwi Python

Tags: python, qiwi

Вопрос такой. Мне нужно с моего qiwi кошелька, используя Python отправить деньги на банковскую карту. Как это можно сделать? Подскажите пожалуйста!

Answer (score 0):

Есть возможность подключить к Python через Qiwi API. С его помощью можно как раз транзакции проводить. Загуглите просто Qiwi API, есть и видеоуроки, и руководства от самого банка.

[QIWI API](https://qiwi.com/api)

Comment: Спасибо, большое.